how to test psycopg with Pytest
I am trying to test execute_query method but it's not work
res:

AssertionError: assert [] == [{'id': 1, 'n...lary': 70000}] E
E         Right contains 3 more items, first extra item: {'id': 1,
'name': 'Alice', 'salary': 50000} E         Use -v to get more diff


class PostgresqlConnection():
dbname: str = PG_ETL_DATABASE
user: str = PG_ETL_USER
password: str = PG_ETL_PASSWORD
host: str = PG_ETL_HOST
port: str = PG_ETL_PORT

@property
def connection(self):
    return psycopg.connect(**self.dict())

def execute_query(self, query, is_fetch_result=False, is_commit=False):
    """Method execute a query on the database"""
    with self.connection as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            results = []
            if is_fetch_result:
                print(f"cursor.description1: {cursor.description.return_value}")
                column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
                print(f"column_names: {column_names}")
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                print(f"rows: {rows}")
                for row in rows:
                    results.append(dict(zip(column_names, row)))
        if is_commit:
            conn.commit()
        return results


The test:
@mock.patch("psycopg.connect")
def test_execute_query(self, mock_connect):
    """test execute query"""
    expected = [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Alice", "salary": 50000},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Bob", "salary": 60000},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Charlie", "salary": 70000},
    ]

    mock_con = mock_connect.return_value
    mock_cur = mock_con.cursor.return_value
    mock_cur.description.return_value = [
        ("id", None, None, None, None, None, None),
        ("name", None, None, None, None, None, None),
        ("salary", None, None, None, None, None, None),
    ]
    mock_cur.fetchall.return_value = [
        (1, "Alice", 50000),
        (2, "Bob", 60000),
        (3, "Charlie", 70000),
    ]
    result = self.resource.execute_query(
        query="q", is_fetch_result=True, is_commit=False
    )
    assert result == expected


Your test isn't testing anything. You've mocked out the connect method and the return value; you're never calling a real function. There's no assert call in your test. In general, unless you're actually developing psycopg, you wouldn't be testing it in your unit tests -- you would be testing your code that interacts with it.

sorry, I did not copy all the test
can you check again

Why would you test an external library
